# adding third party osgi bundle org.amdatu.mongodb as dependencie for compile

Tags: mongodb, gradle, portlet, osgi-bundle, amdatu

I have installed org.amdatu.mongo.jar osgi bundle as well as its depedent bundles on apache felix.

I am able to start it successfully.This basically export pacakge for using mongo service.

Now I have another osgi bundle and I want to access/consume this service in my bundle.I have build.gradle file and bnd.bnd file in my project.Where to give dependencies of this org.amadatu.mongo.jar?

I have used below approache

1)Added org.amdatu.mongo.jar osgi bundle jar in build path by "configure buildpath" option eclipse. NOT WORKING
Here project error removed but when I do buid from build.gradle it gives exception of.
Unable to find symbol import org.amdatu.mongo.mongoDBService.

I am following below link

http://www.amdatu.org/components/mongodb.html

There are no dependencies of the package in central mvn repository for org.amdatu.mongo.jar otherwise I have added it in my build.gradle file.

What should I do so that my project compile successfully?

The osgi bundle in which I want to use this mongo service is a liferaymvcportlet osgi bundle.

Please find project setup and images,

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show your `build.gradle` and probably your `bnd.bnd`.  I had lots of problems with the default gradle `osgi` plugin so I ended up writing my own bnd wrapper.  Gradle is aware this is a problem and has not fixed it.  https://discuss.gradle.org/t/the-osgi-plugin-has-several-flaws/2546/4

Comment: I have added necessary information.

Comment: Liferay hides some of the configuration it added more content in bnd.bnd and gradle files before bundled ....so this files may look irrelevant...

Comment: Looks like your jar isn't being included.  What is the path to your jar? Is it in /libs? If so you just have to add the directory as a flat repository